# Measure to count across multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to Power BI - DAX functions.

I have three columns in a table with text in it and I have added a fourth column where I want the count of these three but when I use `COUNTA`, `COUNTX` or `COUNTAX` measure I am getting the count of the entire column.

```
COUNTA
COUNTAX
COUNTX

Column = COUNTX(Table1, Table1[First_Amendment])
           + COUNTX(Table1, Table1[Second_Amendment])
           + COUNTX(Table1, Table1[Third_Amendment])
```

Suppose column `A`, `B`, `C` contains three names, apple, mango, oranges respectively so in fourth column I should get count as 3.

Comment: In what cases would you not get 3? Are some of the rows blank?

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to count no blank column based on row, right?

If so, you could try to use calculated column like below

```
Column = if((countaa[a])="",0,1)+if((countaa[b])="",0,1)+if((countaa[c])="",0,1)
```

[image]

You also could refer to [this post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Count-number-of-multiple-non-blank-fields-in-a-row/td-p/84176)   for details.

Zoe